# What is the music used in the Frozen Synapse Trailer?

Tags: frozen-synapse, game-music-identification

What is the music used in the Frozen Synapse Trailer, found here:

http://store.steampowered.com/app/98200/

Is it custom written for the game?

Can I get hold of some more of it somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the description [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOlV_9DYnOw):

> Trailer music is by nervous_testpilot
>   and is available as part of the Frozen
>   Synapse Soundtrack Bundle.

The music is written in-house, and will be featured in the game.

Answer (score 1):

This is a section of the track [Welcome to Markov Geist](http://nervoustestpilot.co.uk/track/welcome-to-markov-geist), produced by Mode7 Games' in-house musician and studio co-owner [nervous_testpilot](http://nervoustestpilot.co.uk/).

It can be purchased on its own, as part of the game's [official soundtrack](http://nervoustestpilot.co.uk/album/frozen-synapse-original-soundtrack), or included in the Soundtrack Edition of the game.